# Вывести в отдельный файл и на экран сведения о журналах, пролежавших в киоске более трех месяцев. Подсчитать количество таких журналов

Tags: c#, файлы

Не могу понять как реализовать эту часть задания: "Вывести в отдельный файл и на экран сведения о журналах, пролежавших в киоске более трех месяцев. Подсчитать количество таких журналов". Интересует как сделать часть с сортировкой

А полностью задание звучит так:

> Создать класс Журналы с полями: код, название, месяц, год издания,
> количество страниц, количество штук. Создать файл, содержащий сведения
> о нескольких различных журналах в киоске. Вывести в отдельный файл и
> на экран сведения о  журналах, пролежавших в киоске более трех
> месяцев. Подсчитать количество таких журналов.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace lab1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {   
     
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamWriter write_text;  //Класс для записи в файл
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo("jounarls.txt");
            write_text = file.AppendText(); //Дописываем инфу в файл, если 
            файла не существует он создастся
            write_text.WriteLine("\tКод:\t" + cod.Text +"\n"+ "\tНазвание:\t" + 
           name.Text +"\n" + "\tМесяц:\t" + month.Text +
                "\n"+"\tГод:\t" + years.Text + "\n" + "\tСтраницы:\t" + 
           pages.Text); //Записываем в файл текст из текстового поля 
            write_text.WriteLine("______________________________________");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cod.Text, name.Text, month.Text, years.Text, 
           pages.Text);
            write_text.Close(); // Закрываем файл
        }

        private void read_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("jounarls.txt"); // 
            Открываем файл для чтения
            string str = ""; //Объявляем переменную, в которую будем записывать 
             текст из файла

            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream) //Цикл длиться пока не будет 
                достигнут конец файла
            {
                str += streamReader.ReadLine(); //В переменную str по строчно 
                записываем содержимое файла
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот как написано в задании, прямо так и реализуйте. Создавайте класс Журналы с полями...

Comment: Необходимо решить в каком формате в исходном файле будут храниться данные. Допустим, это json файл.В таком случае вам нужно создать парсер этого файла, саму сущность Журнал, в которую будет парситься единица информации из файла. Потом определить класс логики, в котором будет происходить отбор нужных журналов, подходящих под фильтр (те, которые пролежали более 3-х месяцев).

Если вы опишите более подробно, что значит файл, т.е. в каком формате там хранятся данные, например, json, xml, текстовый(построчно, с разделителем и тд) - сможем более детально помочь и подсказать.